# How to change button order in Ext.Msg?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I have a MessageBox to show in my app, and it is specified that the 'YES' button has to be on the right. How could I change the *YESNOCANCEL* order ? (in a *CANCELNOYES* one maybe?)

Here's my actual code :

```
Ext.Msg.show({
             title: 'myTitle',
             msg: 'myMessage',
             buttonText : {
                 cancel : 'Cancel',
                 yes : 'Yes'
             },
             fn: function(btn) {
                 if(btn == 'yes') {
                     dodat(); 
                 }
             }
        });
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Ext.Msg` is a singleton, so it has an odd lifecycle in comparison to a normal component.  This means that the code below should probably be executed early in the `Ext.onReady` or App creation.  This will change the button order for all alerts in your application also because `Ext.Msg` is a singleton:

```
var msgButtonBar = Ext.Msg.down("toolbar");
var okButton = msgButtonBar.items.items[0];
var yesButton = msgButtonBar.items.items[1];
var noButton = msgButtonBar.items.items[2];
var cancelButton = msgButtonBar.items.items[3];
msgButtonBar.removeAll(false);
msgButtonBar.add([cancelButton, noButton, yesButton, okButton]);
```

It basically just reorders the button in the Singleton.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that this code should only be executed once in total in your whole app.

Comment: Thanks ;) it works like a charm! I wish I could up your answer, but I dont have the reputation recquired :/

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend NOT messing with the `Ext.MessageBox` singleton, and instead just create a custom extension of `Ext.Window`, with the `buttons` config of your choosing.

It is really just some minor configuration to make a window appear like its the message box.  Something like:

```
var msgBox = new Ext.Window({
    width: 300,
    height: 150,
    buttons: [{ text: 'Cancel', handler...}, { text: 'Yes', handler...}],
    title: 'Alert',
    modal: true|false,
    html: 'Are you sure?'
});
msgBox.show();
```

If the styles aren't perfect, you could even add the "ext-mb-dialog", or whatever the classes are, to this window configuration.